# Stock Incoming Shipment OpenERP , access rights for new user?

Tags: odoo, stock

I Tried to create new user in openerp and create a company for him, and give him these right access
**Sales Management ? : Manager 

Warehouse Management ? : Manager

Accounting & Finance ? : Manager

Human Resources ? : Employee

Administration ? : Configuration**
But he Cannot create a incomming shipment order, this raise appear
**AccessError

Operation prohibited by access rules, or performed on an already deleted document (Operation: read, Document type: Location).**
then I deleted domain in Record Rules for Location object the raise disappeared but a new one appeared for Partner Object if skipping it, this raise appears
**Unknown Error

null value in column "account_id" violates not-null constraint**

Comment: this is the main problem in openerp . Its very difficult to debug access rights. Please put the db on a server we can access and I will try to help you

Answer (score 1):

In this issue following possibilities to be considered.

- you have not given access rights to stock location for your new created users.
- And you have not created chart of accounts of your new company.

Comment: I have not created chart of accounts of my company,I will try it.

Comment: Please have a look once and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that access error is arising, but the "Unknown error" you specified here maybe because you haven't specified expense account in products or you haven't specified account receivable and account payable for the partner.